# Fill in empty space with polygons

Tags: arcmap, polygon

I got a habitat map. The empty area is developed area and I want to fill it with grey color. How can I do that efficiently?

I tried to use clip but don't work.

I am using ArcMap 10.5.1 standard

[image]

Comment: Union the dotted bounary and the colored polygons, assuming the dotted boundary is a polygon.. if not you can use Feature to Polygon (Advanced license needed)http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003n000000 to create a polygon in your void area.. If you don't have an advanced license create a new polygon shapefile and trace the dotted boundary to draw a new polygon then Union with your colored polys (Union is limited to two feature classes in Basic and Standard license levels).

Comment: @MichaelStimson if I do a Union, would the result be just a polygon inside the boundary?

Comment: It takes less time to test suggestion, than ask for clarification. It will also show respect to time of others.

Comment: @FelixIP Yes. I have tried. When I do a Union of the boundary and the colored polygons, it gives me the boundary polygon.

Then I need to select the void area from the attribute table and export to a new feature.

Comment: If you want to Erase the colored features from the dashed boundary you can use the erase tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000m000000 which requires an advanced level of license, if you have standard and basic your only choice is to union the two and query your results out, either by Select or as a definition query on your feature layer.. all your ephemeral data should have IDs from the colored polygons of -1 which makes them easy to select.

Comment: There is also an option to use erase tool from et geowizards extention (free) for arcgis --> https://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_NoRestrictions.htm

Comment: Polygon you are after will have color_fid=-1